# IOS8. Close UIPickerView on selection click swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I do have a UIPicker view populated with selection options. I select on of them and click but `UIViewPicker` doesn't close. How do I close it or at least fire the event so that I could hide it programatically?

I looked at `UIPickerViewDelegate` but haven't found any suitable method which would execute not on item selection but only when I click selected item.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

In didSelectRow method just add this line at the end of interaction:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the picker visible once the user clicks in the text field using the textFieldDidBeginEditing function, then hide using the didSelectRow function...

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        myPicker.hidden = false

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        myTextField.text = myPicker[row]
        myPicker.hidden = true

    }
```

I also recommend you add the touchesBegan function to hide it if the user touches any part of the screen outside of the picker view.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

         myPicker.hidden = true

    }
```

I'm of course assuming you've done all required dataSource and delegate linking and functions for the UIPickerView...

Answer (score 0):

use the delegate method of UIPickerView like bellow..

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  ```
  yourTextField.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
  thePickerView.hidden = YES;
  ```

  }

**Update**

you could add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIPickerView:

> UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
>                                    action:@selector(pickerViewTapped];
>   [pickerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

And then:

- (void)pickerViewTapped {
  // dismiss the picker.
  }

Comment: This gets executed when selection is changed. I need method which would be executed when I actually click on the selected item.

Comment: @WildGoat  you can only change the selection in picker view. how you click in picker view?

Comment: Yes you rotate and changing options in the pickerview but as soon as you found required option all you do is clicking on it and picker view disappears. If i put it inside pickerView method it would hide it before I click as soon as change is finished. Did you get my point?